# querySelectorAll didn't working but querySelector did

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Making simple extension for chrome.
Second function didn't work when changing "querySelector" into "querySelectorAll".

```
  var ele2 = document.querySelectorAll(".view-count ");
   window.onload = function(){
        func2();
  }

function func2(){
    ele2.innerHTML = ele2.innerHTML.trim();
    ele2.innerHTML = ele2.innerHTML.slice(0, -14);
    ele2.textContent = "$" + ele2.innerHTML.replace(/&nbsp;/g,' ');
    }
```

**Solution :**

```
for (x=0;x<ele2.length;x++){ele2[x].innerHTML = ele2[x].innerHTML.trim();}
for (x=0;x<ele2.length;x++){ele2[x].innerHTML = ele2[x].innerHTML.slice(0, -14);}
for (x=0;x<ele2.length;x++){ele2[x].textContent = "$" + ele2[x].innerHTML.replace(/&nbsp;/g,' ');}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) returns a collection of nodes as opposed to `querySelector` which returns a single node.
To get to a node in the collection you'll have to reference it via an index.

```
ele2[0].innerHTML = ele2[0].innerHTML.trim();
```

Comment: Thank you. But how can i select all nodes? Not just 0 or 1 or 4 but all, that querySelectorAll could find?

Comment: @pi1yau1u You'll have to loop though them. `for (x=0;x<ele2.length;x++){ele2[x]...}`

Answer (score 0):

querySelector returns first query based of parameter value.
querySelectorAll returns list in array-like structure. To fetch individual element inside list, use index.
Exp,

```
ele2[0]  // first iteration
ele2[1]  // second iteration
```