# Why is QuerySelectorAll not working on my modal page

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors, modal-dialog, queryselector

I'm quite new at coding and trying to teach myself via books and other available sources, so please bare with me.

Does anyone have an idea how to make my close buttons work for all modal pages using `querySelector` or `QuerySelectorAll`? Currently, I'm trying to create a site that shows my artwork. Each piece of work would open up a modal page when you click on it, further describing each piece. For some reason, my close button only seems to work for the first page when I use `QuerySelector`, but when I change it to `querySelectorAll`, the close button does not work properly on any of the pages. I would think I need to use `querySelectorAll`, being that the close button will be on each modal page, and I'm trying to capture all `.closeButton` classes in one shot.

```js
document.getElementById('portfolioPg1').addEventListener('click',
  function() {
    document.querySelector('.modalFish').style.display = 'flex';
  });

document.getElementById('portfolioPg2').addEventListener('click',
  function() {
    document.querySelector('.modalTurtle').style.display = 'flex';
  });


document.querySelector(".closeButton").addEventListener('click',
  function() {
    document.querySelector('.modalFish').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.modalTurtle').style.display = 'none';
  });
```

```html
<div ID="modalPage1" class="modalFish">

  <div class="modalContent" id="modalFishContent">

    <span class="closeButton">+</span>

    <div><img class="modalImg" ID="modalFishImg" src="Images/Fish School.jpg"></div>
    <div>
      <p class="modalTxt">The inspiration behind this piece was Fall foliage. Deep red being one of my favorite colors for the fall, I decided to use this as the background. Being that it's a dark color, it's easy to layer on different colors that will coordinate well, while
        adding a pop to it. </p>

      <p class="modalTxt">Around this time I had been making a few more "simpler" and "cute" pieces, so I wanted to being myself back to making something a little bit more abstract. Although semi simple in design, from afar, the origami pieces appear a bit obscure, almost
        reminicent of a pile of leaves. Looking closely, we can see that the origami is in fact fish swimming in all different driections.
      </p>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>


<div ID="modalPage2" class="modalTurtle">

  <div class="modalContent" ID="modalTurtleContent">

    <span class="closeButton">+</span>

    <div><img class="modalImg" ID="modalTurtleImg" src="Images/Sea Turtle.jpg"></div>
    <div>
      <p class="modalTxt">After a trip to Mallorca, Spain, I discovered a new love for turtles. I ended up going to two aquariums while I was there, and found the turtles to be very cute. The way they slowly moved about, and the way they swam. I remember seeing them all
        stacked piled up on top of each other as one was climbing on top of the other ones, and accidentally knocked one of the turtles into the water.</p>

      <p class="modalTxt">There was something a bit simple, and adorable about these turtles, so I wanted to create a piece that reflected simplicity, and humbleness. I was also inspired by the tropical vibes as well, which led to my color scheme of light blue for the water,
        and brighter colors for each of the turtles. The blue is painted on a bit heavy to represent the waves of the water. In order to achieve a simple and adorable vibe, I needed to focus on having the right colors, and limit the number of turtles
        I had, while making sure I did not take up too much of the blue background.
      </p>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>

<script src="Origami Mami.js"></script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I resolve my problem about flip cards in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68238639/how-can-i-resolve-my-problem-about-flip-cards-in-javascript) this should atleast give you an idea of what is going on

Comment: hei, the simple explainations is using `querySelector` if you are sure that the target element is only one. using `querySelectorAll` if the target element are more than one, querySelectorAll will return you node list of element on selector.  read this: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp and this: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [querySelectorAll didn't working but querySelector did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17636039/queryselectorall-didnt-working-but-queryselector-did)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select all the "Close Button" elements with querySelectorAll() then loop through each one and toggle the state of that exact modal that is in the same parent node ( ".modalContent" in this case ).

You can do that with this code below :

```
document.querySelectorAll('.closeButton').forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        button.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = "none";
    })
})
```

We did use "**parentElement**" twice because we need to go two levels up from the ".closeButton" node to target the **modal**.

**Suggestion :**

Just to improve the quality of your code and make it more dynamic, you can use the same class name "**.modal**" in all of your modals, then to trigger the modal to show you can use **querySelectorAll()** again to select all the modals at once and loop through them, to add the event listener ("**click**"), you can use the code below to do that :

```
document.querySelectorAll('.modal').forEach(modal => {
    modal.addEventListener('click', () => {
        modal.style.display = "flex";
    })
})
```

And if you want to improve even more you can use another class (for example "**active**") to control the toggle the class "**active**" and change the style of the modal instead of changing the style directly from Javascript, you can do that by changing previous code to the code below :

**Javascript** :

```
document.querySelectorAll('.modal').forEach(modal => {
    modal.addEventListener('click', () => {
        modal.classList.add('active');
    })
})

document.querySelectorAll('.closeButton').forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        button.parentElement.parentElement.style.classList.remove('active');
    })
})
```

**CSS :**

```
.modal {
    display: none;
}

.modal.active {
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: This is beyond helpful in so many ways. Thank you so much. :)